# How to use VSTS pipeline variable in YAML?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have defined a variable in the pipeline and set it to false/true. However, when the pipeline is set, I can see that the value for parameters.RunUnitTest is $(RunUnitTest), and this is not the value I set up in the pipeline. So what I am doing wrong here?

```
trigger: none

extends:
  template: ThunderPipeline.yaml
  parameters:
      MergeBetweenBranches: true
      FromBranch: 'master'
      ToBranch: 'R_Current_Sprint'
      RunUnitTest: '$(RunUnitTest)'
```

Comment: Stupid me, looks like I need to do this variables['RunUnitTest']

Answer (score 0):

Variables can be defined in one YAML and included in another template. This could be useful if you want to store all of your variables in one file. If you are using a template to include variables in a pipeline, the included template can only be used to define variables. You can use steps and more complex logic when you are extending from a template. Use parameters instead of variables when you want to restrict type.

In this example, the variable `favoriteVeggie` is included in `azure-pipelines.yml`.

```
# File: vars.yml
variables:
  favoriteVeggie: 'brussels sprouts'

# File: azure-pipelines.yml

variables:
- template: vars.yml  # Template reference

steps:
- script: echo My favorite vegetable is ${{ variables.favoriteVeggie }}.
```

Or something like:

```
# File: templates/steps-with-params.yml

parameters:
- name: 'runExtendedTests'  # defaults for any parameters that aren't specified
  type: boolean
  default: false

steps:
- script: npm test
- ${{ if eq(parameters.runExtendedTests, true) }}:
  - script: npm test --extended

# File: azure-pipelines.yml

steps:
- script: npm install

- template: templates/steps-with-params.yml  # Template reference
  parameters:
    runExtendedTests: 'true'
```